# How many players play tennis and football?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

There are $300$ boys who represent a team in sports in summer and in winter. In summer $60$ plays cricket and the remainder play tennis. In winter they must play football or hockey but not both. $56$% of the hockey players play cricket in summer and $30$% of the cricket players play hockey in winter. How many boys play tennis and football ?

As from given I can conclude that $18$ of the cricket players play hockey and 42 of the cricket players play football in winters and 240 players plat Tennis but I am not able proceed further. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: These numbers don't add up. Let $H$ be the number of hockey players. Then $\frac{56}{100}H = 18$, the total number playing both hockey and cricket, as you've already calculated. But that means $H = 32\frac 1 7$. Perhaps one of the boys is cheating and spending 1 day a week on hockey, while playing football on the other 6?

Answer (score 1):

If one assumes that the percentage of hockey players that also play cricket is only approximate (see my comment to the OP), then we can take the number of hockey players to be $32$ (percentage playing cricket is $56.25\%$). From here it is just a matter subtracting:

- Number of football players $= 300 -32 = 268$.
- Number of hockey players playing tennis $ = 32 - 18 = 14$.
- Number of tennis players playing football $= 240 -14 = 226$.

But again, that depends on my assumption about resolving the number mismatch being correct.